# Fibers of a locally trivial fibration are diffeomorphic

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, fibration

There is an "immediate" corollary in this paper that is not so immediate for me :

https://people.math.osu.edu/george.924/Ehresmann%20Theorem

This paper proves Ehresmann’s Theorem which states that every proper submersion $F:M\rightarrow N$ is locally trivial. In other words, to every point $p\in N$ corresponds a neighborhood $U$ and a diffeomorphism $\Psi:F^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times F^{-1}(p)$ such that : $F|_{F^{-1}(U)}=\pi\circ\Psi$, where $\pi:U\times F^{-1}(p)\rightarrow U$ is the natural projection.

What I am not able to prove is that if $F$ is a proper submersion, then all of its fibers are diffeomorphic using the theorem stated above. I think the reason why I can't seem to get a hold on that is because the theorem gives a local result, so I can't see how the theorem would help if I pick two arbitrary points in $N$ and and if I want to prove that their preimages are diffeomorphic.

Comment: Suppose $q$ is the other point you pick. If $q \in U$, can you see why $F^{-1}(p)$ and $F^{-1}(q)$ are diffeomorphic?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese No sorry.

Comment: You need to first figure out why this is true before you can get to your desired conclusion. Hint: use $\Psi$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks for your help. I proved that for any two preimages of two points in $U$ are diffeomorphic. How can we generalize this to all $N$?

Comment: That was step 1. Now suppose $q \not\in U$. By local triviality, there is some open set $V$ with $q \in V$ and a diffeomorphism $\Phi : \pi^{-1}(V) \to V\times F^{-1}(q)$ such that $F|_{F^{-1}(V)} = \pi\circ\Phi$. For step 2, can you show that $F^{-1}(p)$ and $F^{-1}(q)$ are diffeomorphic if $U\cap V \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese This is evident, it suffices to choose a point in the intersection and apply transitivity. What is step 3? :) I'll write a full answer to my question once all of this is done and dusted

Comment: The third and final step can be expressed in a couple of ways, but I think the easiest is to choose a path from $p$ to $q$ (here we need $N$ to be connected, otherwise the claim is false). Then by compactness of the path, you can find a finite sequence of open sets which cover the path and contain diffeomorphic preimages. By the transitivity you just mentioned, you find that $F^{-1}(p)$ and $F^{-1}(q)$ are diffeomorphic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136870/discussion-between-random-exchanger-and-michael-albanese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p\in N$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ and a diffeomorphism $\Psi:F^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times F^{-1}(p)$ such that : $F|_{F^{-1}(U)}=\pi\circ\Psi$. First, let's consider $q\in U$. Define $\pi':U\times F^{-1}(p)\rightarrow F^{-1}(p)$ the other projection. And define also $\Theta:=\pi'\circ\Psi:F^{-1}(q)\rightarrow F^{-1}(p)$. $\Theta$ is a bijection whose inverse is given explicitely by $\Theta^{-1}:F^{-1}(p)\rightarrow F^{-1}(q),y\mapsto\Psi^{-1}(q,y)$. It is not hard to see that $\Theta$ and $\Theta^{-1}$ are both smooth maps.

Now let's consider a point $z\notin U$, so there exists a neighborhood $V$ and a diffeomorphism $\Psi':F^{-1}(V)\rightarrow V\times F^{-1}(z)$ such that : $F|_{F^{-1}(V)}=\pi\circ\Psi$. If suppose that there exists a point $q\in U\cap V$, then there exist two diffeomorphisms $\Theta_1:F^{-1}(p)\rightarrow F^{-1}(q)$ and $\Theta_2:F^{-1}(q)\rightarrow F^{-1}(z)$. $\Theta_2\circ\Theta_1$ does the job.

Let's suppose $N$ is connected, so there's a path from $p$ to $z$. We can cover this path with a finite set of open balls that interset one after the other. So the final result is proven.